# QGIS2web fails to preview or export

Tags: qgis, qgis2web

I'm trying to export a map for OpenLayers. Unfortunately, the preview window will only show the tools and my background color. This is also true of exported files when viewed via export.html OpenLayers functionality seems to be working in that I can zoom and draw measuring lines, but no lines, polys, points, or even rasters appear.

I get this error message at the end of the export attempts. I have no idea what this means or what I should do.

[image]

Comment: Export does not seem to like the symbol rules that you have for cities. If finds scale value 0 and tries to use it in division.

Comment: @user30184 I removed the symbol rules, and this didn't fix anything.

Comment: Didn't it even change the error message? Actually the text in red deals with labels.

Comment: @user30184 No, it did not. I'm wondering if the plugin doesn't work with the current release candidate. I may have to abandon OpenLayers and use Leaflet, as Leaflet works just fine. Kinda. It seems to think pixel measurements are about 1cm.

Answer (score 1):

QGIS2web throws errors in the following situations:

- layer style is not compatible with the plugin extraction conditions (QGIS2web prefers rather simple styling instead of advanced)
- Some "weird" symbols occur in your data attribute table - I mean mostly the "%" symbol, but potentially others such as this too. Keep your attribute column name simple

I would advise you not to export a whole project in one go, but keep switching on layer by layer and see which one is faulty.
Check the detailed answer here:

[QGIS2WEB won't open custom layers](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/241621/qgis2web-wont-open-custom-layers/420339#420339)