# How do I modify S57 data converted using ogr2ogr so that it correctly exports on qgis2web?

Tags: qgis, leaflet, openlayers, ogr2ogr, qgis2web

I have some unencrypted ENC charts with file extension .000 (S57 data). Using the process and S52 styles at https://www.sigterritoires.fr/index.php/affichage-des-cartes-marines-s57-dans-qgis/ I have converted the chart into shape files, and opened them using the downloaded project file which generates the correct symbology. This is done using the following code:
`ogr2ogr -skipfailures target source`

The whole chart opens fine in QGis and I have all the relevant layers, symbols and features.
[image: Chart working in qGIS]
The issue arises when I try and use qgis2web to save the chart in a web format. As soon as I have any layer in my chart available, the entire web map is blank in the preview and in the export. The expected behaviour is for my chart to export on top of the base map, with the styling matching or close to what I see in QGis. The issue is that inclusion of my layers breaks the entire export.
[image: Blank export preview with custom layer]

If I import a single layer (DEPARE, for example) into a new project to make it more straightforward to see what's going on, I can check the 'Fields' section to ensure none have spaces or illegal characters ([QGIS2WEB won't open custom layers](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/241621/qgis2web-wont-open-custom-layers)), and can also check the styling to ensure it is all 'simple', as per the question above again.
[image: Fields section containing no illegal characters]
[image: Simple styling]
Checking or unchecking 'Use Project CRC' does not have any impact on the export.

Having tried all the suggestions I have been able to research, I have had no success. The presence of any layer containing my chart data will break the qgis2web export. If my layer is not selected, the base map exports fine.
[image: Base Map exporting fine]

Is there something I can do to my data to clean it up for export perhaps? There are so many layers across the board on the full chart that it could be a time consuming process, but the nature of my project is that I only need to do this once.

Comment: I think it's a reference systems problem. Can you provide your DEPARE shp file? Upload it somewhere and link it here. Thanks.

Comment: The geometries must also be seen well. For example, if there are self-intersecting geometries or geometries with errors, the export may fail. Maybe this is the case as I see that qgis2web creates the graphics well in the preview, but I can't see the data. You should export and see what errors come up in the browser console.

Comment: What are errors in the console and/or network section in browser debugger when you open you exported map in browser?

Comment: Thanks @andreaordonselli - the depare shp is at http://www.tastetheblue.co.uk/s57test/DEPARE.shp

Comment: Exception in layer DEPARE with renderer SINGLE: FILL SYMBOL (1 layers) color 190,178,151,255,rgb:0.74,0.59,1: Traceback: File "/qgis2web/olStyleScripts.py", line 47, in exportStyles useMapUnits) = singleSymbol(renderer, stylesFolder, File "/qgis2web/olStyleScripts.py", line 213, in singleSymbol useMapUnits) = getSymbolAsStyle(symbol, stylesFolder, File "/qgis2web/olStyleScripts.py", line 527, in getSymbolAsStyle fillColor = getRGBAColor(props["color"], alpha) File "/qgis2web/utils.py", line 633, in getRGBAColor r, g, b, a = color.split(",") ValueError: too many values to unpack (expected 4)

Comment: @TomazicM lots of local resource font errors, and this:
[Error] AssertionError: Assertion failed. See https://openlayers.org/en/v6.4.3/doc/errors/#41 for details.
 lt (ol.js:8:30812)
 (anonymous function) (ol.js:8:356644)
 (anonymous function) (ol.js:8:356718)
 e (ol.js:8:355657)
 e (ol.js:8:423906)
 Global Code (layers.js:24)

Comment: You have only linked the .shp file, you must link a zip file that contains the files that make up the shp. They are several files located in the same folder with the same name.

Comment: Apologies @andreaordonselli - http://www.tastetheblue.co.uk/s57test/depare.zip

Answer (score 0, accepted):

qgis2web has no problem exporting your data.
However, the project and layer EPSG must be correctly defined. Not knowing the reference system with which the data was created, I cannot superimpose it on the openstreetmap

[image]

[image]

Comment: What did you change the CRS to in order to get the export preview to display? I have tried setting it to EPSG:4326 for both the project and the layer and this hasn't solved it. The data is WGS84 so I believe EPSG:4326 to be correct.

Comment: Update - it appears that the issue is in the latest release of QGis. If I open my files using the LTR then I get the expected output. Many thanks for your help.

Comment: Thanks for your test on different qgis versions. I will investigate this issue with the new qgis version. Consider supporting qgis2web by donating a virtual coffee from the github home.  Greetings.

Comment: Absolutely. Coffee on way. There is also a glitch in qgis2web where if you change the output folder, when you click 'open' it closes the entire plugin. Do I submit that somewhere?

Comment: this should also be a problem with the new version of qt.  you don't need to write elsewhere, I'll note it. Thanks